# How to invoke Flutter Desktop app's functionality from a Flutter Chrome extension?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, biometrics

I've created a simple Chrome extension using Flutter and inside it, there's a button. On click, I want to call my Flutter Desktop app's in front and invoke its biometrics function.

I can call my Desktop app in front using plugin from the Flutter labs: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-github-client#5

However, I want to do this from the Chrome extension itself. Is this even possible with JavaScript events or deeplink?

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.